# Why does "git checkout <branch> – <file>” overwrite changes without warning?

Tags: git

When I use the command `git checkout <branch> – <file>` the file is forcibly overwritten without any conflict warning, even it had modifications. Is this behavior specified anywhere? Why doesn’t git show a conflict warning?

Comment: It's designed, as mentioned in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203).

Comment: The docs for `checkout branch -- path` start with "Overwrite the contents of the files that match the pathspec"

Answer (score 0):

#### The behavior you described is intentional and documented in Git's official documentation:

### Purpose

The `git checkout <branch> -- <file>` command is designed to overwrite the specified file in your working tree with the version from the given branch, discarding any local changes.

### No Conflict Warnings

Git doesn't show conflict warnings in this case because it assumes you intentionally want to replace the file with the version from the other branch, even if it means losing uncommitted modifications.

### Breakdown of Why This Behavior Makes Sense

1. **Explicit Intent**: The `--` argument explicitly signals that you want to overwrite the file, differentiating it from switching branches entirely.
2. **Local Changes as Transient**: Git views uncommitted changes as temporary, so it's not unusual for commands to discard them if needed.
3. **Preserving Flexibility**: This behavior allows for flexibility in managing file versions and integrating changes from different branches.

### Strategies to Avoid Accidental Overwrites

To avoid accidental overwrites, consider these strategies:

1. **Commit or Stash Changes**: If you want to preserve local modifications, commit them or use `git stash` before checking out the file from another branch.
2. **Use `git restore` for More Control**: The `git restore` command, introduced in Git 2.23, offers more granular control over file checkouts and might provide conflict warnings in certain scenarios.
3. **Review Status Beforehand**: Use `git status` to check for uncommitted changes before using `git checkout`.
4. **Consider Safer Alternatives**: If you're unsure, use `git show <branch>:<file>` to view the file's content from the other branch without overwriting your working tree.

By understanding the purpose and nuances of `git checkout <branch> -- <file>`, you can use it effectively while minimizing the risk of unintentional data loss.